# Handling tableview cell selection from other view controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitableview

I have a `tableView` with custom table cells which displays a list of sayings. While selecting a cell (say "saying1") from the `tableView`, the cell will get selected and will moves to next view controller for showing an explanation of selected saying. In that view controller two buttons **"Previous"** and **"Next"** are there for navigating to previous and next saying. So user may select next button for seeing next saying (say "saying2"). But the problem here is, In this stage when i navigate back to my  `tableview`, the cell selected will be "saying1" not "saying2".

In order to solve this problem, i collected the currently selected sayings ("saying2's") index from array (ie,index will be 1) and passed it to the previous `tableView` through segue and converted that value into `NSIndexpath`. After this step i don't know what to do. Please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specifically select a cell by calling following method present in UITableView class :

```
selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:
```

refere to following link : [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/selectRowAtIndexPath%3aanimated%3ascrollPosition):